# How to pass 'nonce' option to the @emotion/cache which is a dependency of @emotion/core?

Tags: content-security-policy, storybook, emotion, storybook-addon-specifications, emotion-js

Using storybook for preact demos and webpack bundles @emotion/core -> @emotion/cache -> @emotion/sheet which is inserting styles to iframe headers causing multiple CSP errors for styles like below

```
<head>
    <style data-emotion>...</style>
    <style data-emotion>...</style>
    <style data-emotion>...</style>
    <style data-emotion>...</style>
    <style data-emotion>...</style>
    ...
</head>
```

I tried checking the following docs - https://emotion.sh/docs/cache-provider, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/sheet/v/10.0.0-really-unsafe-please-do-not-use.1?activeTab=dependents to pass the nonce but we do not create StyleSheet / createCache within any component, but webpack bundles all dependencies from package.json as a part of theme and it applies default options ( nonce - undefined)

I tried adding CacheProvider to storybook decorators globally like below

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import React from 'react';

const styleCache = createCache({
  key: 'prefix',
  nonce: 'nonce-id',
});

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <div id="cache-block">
      <CacheProvider value={styleCache}>
        <Story />
      </CacheProvider>
    </div>
  ),
];
```

I can see cache-block is rendered but the header styles are not updated with the nonce value.
If I miss anything here or if there's another way to pass nonce for emotion-styles please let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: By any chance did you find solution?